# Second Derivative of log

Tags: derivatives

Let: $\log(s)=z$

I understand that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} =  e^{-z}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

What is the second derivative, ie $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}$

Applying the Product rule I reach the following:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = e^{-z}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \right ) $$

Is this correct or should we reach to:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2} =e^{-2z}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial z}  \right )$$

Comment: You're trying to partial differentiante **what** ? The symbol $\;\frac\partial{\partial s}\;$ seems to be lacking the target function...

Comment: This is a fragment of the step from transforming the black scholes PDE to log space and constant coefficients in order to get to the heat equation.. I just want to express d/ds as a function of d/dz given that s=e^z